# following-sibling::text() only if contains needle

Tags: xpath

In PHP-Xpath i get text between `<br />` tags like:

```
//*/br/following-sibling::text()
```

How can i get this text only if contains *'needle'*?

Something like `br[contains(.,'needle')]` - or - `following-sibling::*contains(.,'needle')/text()`

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Use**:

```
following-sibling::text()[contains(., 'needle')]
```